# Build hash using values from another hash

Tags: ruby

```
Hash1 = {
    map1: {city: 'Berlin', country: 'Germany'},
    map2: {city: 'Toronto', country: 'Canada'},
    map3: {city: 'Boston', country: 'USA' }
}
```

Okay so I want to build a hash that looks as follows:

```
newHash = {
    Berlin: 'map1',
    Toronto: 'map2',
    Boston: 'map3' 
}
```

How do I loop through `Hash1` and build `newHash`.

```
Hash1.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), acc|
  # what do I do inside this loop?
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert the strings to symbols and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash1.map { |k, v| [v[:city].to_sym, k.to_s] }.to_h
#⇒ {:Berlin=>"map1", :Toronto=>"map2", :Boston=>"map3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
  map1: {city: 'Berlin', country: 'Germany'},
  map2: {city: 'Toronto', country: 'Canada'},
  map3: {city: 'Boston', country: 'USA' }
}

new_data = data.reduce({}) { |h, (k, v)| h[v[:city].to_sym] = k.to_s; h }

puts new_data #=> {:Berlin=>"map1", :Toronto=>"map2", :Boston=>"map3"}
```

Comment: Consider to use `each_with_object` here. Besides ugly `; h`, `reduce` recreates the object on each iteration.

Comment: @mudasobwa `reduce` doesn't recreate the object. It passes the object which is returned by the block into the next iteration. So if the block returns the same object (like `h` above), no additional objects will be created. (nonetheless, `each_with_object` would be the better tool)

Comment: @Stefan oh, indeed, I stated it wrong, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing just one of many methods below

```
new_hash = Hash.new
Hash1.each do |key, value|
     new_hash[value[:city]] = key
end
```

Comment: Please avoid abusing `each` with preliminary created local variable instead of `map`/`reduce`. Also, `value['city']` would be `nil`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why using `each`, a bad idea here?

Comment: `each` is for enumerating. `reduce`/`each_with_object` is for reducing. The code is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = {}
hash.each do |key, value|
  output[:"#{value[:city]}"] = key.to_s
end

puts output
# {:Berlin=>"map1", :Toronto=>"map2", :Boston=>"map3"}
```

For the exact output style, you have to use the Ruby 1.9 or higher version.

Comment: You are abusing `each` with preliminary created local variable. Use `each_with_object` instead.